# How to copy DateTaken tag from another image using ExifTool?

Tags: metadata, exiftool

I want to copy EXIF Date Created Tag from one image to another.I understand that i can copy all details using

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile a.jpg b.jpg
```

This copies all tags from a.jpg to file `b` if its only im JPEG format.If the file is in PNG format,the tool does not update the image.Is it due to difference in image formats?

I just need to copy the DateCreated Tag from the source image.Will this support all image formats?
How can i do this? Please advice.

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: Closely related: [Is "Date Taken" Exif data possible on .PNG file, and is it possible to copy "Date Modified" to "Date Taken"?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/64552)

Comment: Also related: [Use DateCreated for DateTaken (CreationTime) on a PNG using ExifTool](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/86146)

Comment: Related: [How to add author and other properties to PNG files?](//photo.stackexchange.com/a/75716)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a couple issues to note:

- DateTaken is a Windows properties, not a tag in a file.  Windows fills the DateTaken value from a variety of tags.
- PNG files do not support EXIF metadata.  There is a non-standard way of inserting EXIF metadata but it isn't supported by Windows.  You could copy `DateCreated` to `XMP:DateCreated`, but Windows doesn't read XMP metadata from PNG files.

In the case of PNG files, Windows fills the DateTaken property from the `PNG:CreationTime` tag.  So you'll need to copy `DateCreated` to `PNG:CreationTime`.  You can do that with this command

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile SourceFile "-PNG:CreationTime<DateCreated" TargetFile
```

This is pretty much a special case for PNG files.  Most other filetypes, Jpgs, Tiffs, RAW files, support EXIF metadata and you could use this command in those cases

```
exiftool -TagsFromFile SourceFile -DateCreated TargetFile
```

Actually, I suggest that you use either `DateTimeOriginal` or `CreateDate` instead of `DateCreated`.  `DateCreated` is an IPTC legacy tag, is less likely to be in your file, and only holds the Date value and not the Time value.  `DateTimeOriginal` and `CreateDate` are EXIF tags that are much more likely to be in most files.  PNG files still need to use PNG:CreationTime.

Comment: To clarify, there is no such thing as a Date Taken tag.  That is a Windows property.  In the case of Jpgs and Tiffs, Windows reads a variety of tags (`EXIF:DateTimeOriginal`, `IPTC:DateCreated + IPTC:TimeCreated`,  `XMP:CreateDate`,  `EXIF:CreateDate`, `XMP:DateTimeOriginal`, in that order) in order to fill that property.  In the case of PNG files, Windows only reads `PNG:CreationTime`.